Fix Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget' during downgrade version 17 to 16
i have a new project which develop with angular 17 but now i need to downgrade to angular v16 so, i have a problem path.
I update all version in package.json file but i don't get solution for this error.
Do you have any idea for that ?
I also check different topic about this subject in stackOverflow but i don't get solution.
npm run serve_proxy    

> car-angular@0.0.0 serve_proxy
> ng serve --verbose --proxy-config proxy.config.json

Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.

{
  "name": "car-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --base-href=.",
    "build_prod": "ng build --configuration production --base-href=.",
    "build_dev": "ng build --base-href=.",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "serve_proxy": "ng serve --verbose --proxy-config proxy.config.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@costlydeveloper/ngx-awesome-popup": "^3.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^16.3.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^16.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^16.9.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "20.12.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}

{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "car-angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/car-angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "outputHashing": "media"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "car-angular:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "car-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}


You also need to  replace all styleUrl to styleUrls and make sure the property is an array and not a string
You have to rename all the "buildTarget" to "browserTarget" in the angular.json file.
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "car-angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/car-angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "outputHashing": "media"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "car-angular:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "car-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

Please find below stackblitz with a fresh angular 16 project for reference
Stackblitz Demo

The situation changed after we replaced them.
My declarations of css style files in components and css nesting are no longer recognized as valid.

Like : ````    src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:64:13:
64 │ export class SharedModule {}
╵              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
X [ERROR] TS2345: Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; styleUrl: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'styleUrl' does not exist in type 'Component'. Did you mean to write 'styleUrls'? [plugin angular-compiler]
src/app/auth/components/login-email-id/login-email-id.component.ts:14:2:
  14 │   styleUrl: './login-email-id.component.scss',



@Sodiki try checking the package.json for angular 16, maybe typescript version is not downgraded, you have to install the specific version of angular 16 npm i @angular/cli@16.x.x then create a new project then compare the versions in package.json with your code

@Sodiki I think you need to replace all styleUrl to styleUrls and make sure the property is an array and not a string, this will solve your issue!

I had many error with angular/compiler:
NG5002: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) [plugin angular-compiler]
dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",

⠸ Building...▲ [WARNING] A nested style rule cannot start with "label" because it looks like the start of a declaration [plugin angular-compiler] [css-syntax-error]
src/app/shared/styles/home.css:50:2:
  50 │   label {
     │   ~~~~~
     ╵   :is(label)


@Sodiki its just a warning, just fix the CSS, hope you issue is resolved

It Ok,
Thank you.
